# Force class derived from abstract class to implement constructor

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, abstract-class, abstract

I have a custom exception which looks like the following:

```
public abstract class MyException : Exception
{
    public MyException()
    {
    }

    public MyException(string message) : base(message)
    {
    }

    public MyException(string message, Exception inner) : base(message, inner)
    {

    }

    public abstract HttpStatusCode GetHttpStatusCode();
}
```

And a derived class:

```
public class ForbiddenException : MyException
{
    public override HttpStatusCode GetHttpStatusCode()
    {
        return HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;
    }
}
```

I want the derived classes to either use, or be forced to implement, the constructor formats in the abstract class.

Currently using the above, when I try to create a `ForbiddenException`, I get the following error:

```
throw new ForbiddenException("Request forbidden");
```

`ForbiddenException does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments`

I could manually put the constructors into each derived class of `MyException` but this is error prone + repeating myself.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: You can't. Constructors aren't inherited, it's just up to each class to implement the appropriate ones. I think tools like ReSharper (IIRC) will prompt you if you're derived from Exception to provide all four constructors and the serialization override.

Comment: The other thing I could do is - instead of having an abstract base class - I could just make each custom exception derive from `Exception` and implement a custom interface like `IHasHttpStatusCode` which contains the `GetHttpStatusCode` method... Not sure which I prefer though

Comment: You could as well just use composition and a factory. It may not play as well with try/catch matching, but `throw HttpResponseExceptions.forbidden('optional message');` where it returns a new instance of `HttpResponseException`. The downside is that you would have to catch `HttpResponseException` and then check it's code rather than matching, a switch on the code would most likely be as readable.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid copying & pasting/errors when re-writing, consider using a Text Template. I've placed this in a `.tt` template in my toy class library, which I also copied your `MyException` into:

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="false" language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
using System;

namespace ClassLibrary2
{

<# StandardConstructors("public","ForbiddenException","MyException"); #>

}
<#+
  public void StandardConstructors(string modifiers,
       string derivedException, string baseException)
    {
        Write(modifiers);
        Write(" partial class ");
        Write(derivedException);
        Write(":");
        WriteLine(baseException);
        WriteLine("{");

        Write("\tpublic ");
        Write(derivedException);
        WriteLine("() {}");

        Write("\tpublic ");
        Write(derivedException);
        WriteLine("(string message):base(message)");
        WriteLine("\t{}");

        Write("\tpublic ");
        Write(derivedException);
        WriteLine("(string message, Exception inner):base(message,inner)");
        WriteLine("\t{}");

        WriteLine("}");
    }
#>
```

The only error I immediately get is I've not implemented `GetHttpStatusCode` but I'd expect you to be writing that in a separate file that also defines the same partial `ForbiddenException` class. Each new derived exception just needs you to add another `StandardConstructors` line to the template file. Far less error prone.

Of course, you can make this as fancy as you like, I just wrote this from scratch in a few minutes<sup>1</sup>.

This is one the above template produces:

```
using System;

namespace ClassLibrary2
{

public partial class ForbiddenException:MyException
{
    public ForbiddenException() {}
    public ForbiddenException(string message):base(message)
    {}
    public ForbiddenException(string message, Exception inner):base(message,inner)
    {}
}

}
```

Not pretty but it doesn't have to be - it's generated code.

---

<sup>1</sup>E.g. if the tabs/spacing really irks you, but also if e.g. you want to have more control over modifiers, etc.